# ruby on rails, replace last character if it is a * sign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a string and I need to check whether the last character of that string is *, and if it is, I need to remove it.

```
if stringvariable.include? "*"
 newstring = stringvariable.gsub(/[*]/, '')
end
```

The above does not search if the '*' symbol is the LAST character of the string.

How do i check if the last character is '*'?

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use the `$` anchor to only match the end of line:

```
"sample*".gsub(/\*$/, '')
```

If there's the possibility of there being more than one * on the end of the string (and you want to replace them all) use:

```
"sample**".gsub(/\*+$/, '')
```

Comment: It has to be noted, that with the answer above you need to operate on the returned value. For in-place replacement use `.gsub!`

Comment: Excellent answer, but what if we want to check both '*' and ',' and if found replace it with ' ' white space ?

Comment: @Vishal do you mean like this? `"sample*,".gsub(/[\*,]+$/, ' ')`

Answer (score 36):

You can also use `chomp` ([see it on API Dock](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/chomp)), which removes the trailing record separator character(s) by default, but can also take an argument, and then it will remove the end of the string only if it matches the specified character(s).

```
"hello".chomp            #=> "hello"
"hello\n".chomp          #=> "hello"
"hello\r\n".chomp        #=> "hello"
"hello\n\r".chomp        #=> "hello\n"
"hello\r".chomp          #=> "hello"
"hello \n there".chomp   #=> "hello \n there"
"hello".chomp("llo")     #=> "he"
"hello*".chomp("*")      #=> "hello"
```

Comment: really it helped more than any other replies

Answer (score 10):

String has an `end_with?` method

```
stringvariable.chop! if stringvariable.end_with? '*'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following which will remove the offending character, if present.  Otherwise it will do nothing:

```
your_string.sub(/\*$/, '')
```

If you want to remove more than one occurrence of the character, you can do:

```
your_string.sub(/\*+$/, '')
```

Of course, if you want to modify the string in-place, use sub! instead of sub

Cheers,
Aaron

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a regex or just splice the string:

```
if string_variable[-1] == '*'
  new_string = string_variable.gsub(/[\*]/, '') # note the escaped *
end
```

That only works in Ruby 1.9.x...

Otherwise you'll need to use a regex:

```
if string_variable =~ /\*$/
  new_string = string_variable.gsub(/[\*]/, '') # note the escaped *
end
```

But you don't even need the `if`:

```
new_string = string_variable.gsub(/\*$/, '')
```